# is there way to convert all inline css to external stylesheet

Tags: php, css

I am having a around hundred of php files with inline css. I want to convert all these inline css to external stylesheet automatically. Is there any script available for this which can assign class or id if no class and id is present and writes the inline style to css file. Already tried cssout.com website but it is generating error in php code.

I am looking for kind of scripts in python or .net or java or any platform that can do this task.

Comment: Asking for software/tools is EXPLICITLY off-topic

Comment: it can be anything a python script or javascript or .net script or anything. Editing the title and removing the word tool

Comment: My recommendations is to use the examples and learn what they're doing. Reverse it that way, probably dead simple

Comment: @DarylGill. Reversing it is not involving a way to create a file and write it. Neither the reverse process involves applying classes if it doesn't exist in html. The conversion of external stylesheet to inline css is easy. Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend php's [DOM class](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

Use it like this:

```
       $html ='your inline html'; 
       $dom = new DOMDocument;
       @$dom->loadHTML($html);

       $only_divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
       $only_paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

       //or every element
       $all_elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
```

then process every element (or divs/p only)

```
        foreach ($all_elements as $element){
            if ( !empty( $style = $element->getAttribute('style')) ){
                //style in this element is not empty, try to get class

                if ( !empty( $class = $element->getAttribute('class')) ){
                   // this element already have class
                   // do something
                }

                if ( !empty( $id = $element->getAttribute('id')) ){
                   // this element have id
                   // do something 
                }

                if ( empty($id) && empty($class) ){
                    //this element have neither
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Trying this way. Thanks. I appreciate your help